# Number of digits in Epoch time

Tags: linux, unix, epoch

I'm working on a machine which has some code running on it which sets the time when I set the password. The time set is epoch time, but it has 13 digits in it, and when I wrote a simple program to get the epoch time and ran it on my personal computer running linux, it returns the epoch time which has 10 digits. Would anyone know what the extra three digits signify?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably seconds vs milliseconds.

You'd have to consult the specific documentation though.